# Blank screen in reackhooks Home page with Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

I am trying the send `axios` get request to `server.js`, which send a GET request to contentful website. I am getting no data in Home.js and getting following error in console. Could someone please help me to identify the issue here ?
I could see data displaying in `setSearchResults` while setting a break point, please refer screenshot attached.

[image]

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
> component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either
> doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on
> every render.
> in Home (created by Context.Consumer)
> in Route (at App.js:18)
> in Switch (at App.js:17)
> in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
> in BrowserRouter (at App.js:15)
> in App (at src/index.js:11)
> in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
> in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:10)

`Home.js`

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { usePosts } from "../custom-hooks/";
import Moment from 'moment';
import { Wave } from "react-animated-text";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Home() {

    const [posts, isLoading] = usePosts();
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
    const [showColor, setShowColor] = useState("");
    const [findTag, setFindTag] = useState("");
    //const isMounted = useRef(false);

    /* In the Home tab, system displays all the published blogs from contentful website. 
       We can search for the blogs in the search area provided. Also on click on the tags should filter
       the blogs records.
    */

     
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
    }

    
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/service/blogpost');
            setSearchResults(res.data.items);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
        fetchData();
      }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const results = searchResults.filter(blog =>
            blog.fields.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) || blog.fields.title.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm) || blog.fields.shortDescription.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
            || blog.fields.shortDescription.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm)
        );
        setSearchResults(results);
    }, [searchTerm, searchResults]);

    const getFilterTags = (event) => {
        const tagText = event.target.innerText;
        console.log("Print tag of a:"+tagText);
        const results = searchResults.filter(blog =>
            blog.fields.title.toLowerCase().includes(tagText) || blog.fields.title.toUpperCase().includes(tagText) 
        );
        setSearchResults(results);
    }


   
    const renderPosts = () => {
      if (isLoading) return(<div className="loadingIcon"> <p className="noSearchData">Loading...</p> </div>);

      return (
        <div className="wrap">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="column left" >
                    <h3>Search:</h3>
                    <label>
                        <div className="playerSearch_Home">
                            <div className="playerSearch_Icon">
                                <input type="text" className="playerSearch_Home_Input" placeholder="search posts..." value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange} />
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <h3>Tags:</h3>
                    <label>
                        {
                            searchResults.map(({ fields: { id, tags } }) => (
                                <div key={id} className="techtags">
                                    {
                                         Array.isArray(tags) ? (
                                            tags.map((tag) => (
                                             <a onClick={getFilterTags} className="grouptechtags" style={{backgroundColor: `${showColor}`},{ marginRight: "10px" }} key={tag}>{tag}</a>
                                              ))
                                           ) : (
                                             <a onClick={getFilterTags} style={{backgroundColor: `${showColor}`}} className="grouptechtags">{tags}</a>
                                          )
                                    }
                                </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </label>
                    <div className="twitterlink">
                        <a href="">Follow me on twitter</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="reactStunning">
                    ️ Built with react...!
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <small className="copyright">© 2020 Soccerway</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="column right" >
                    {!searchResults.length && (<div> <p className="noSearchData"><Wave text="No results available...!"/></p> </div>)}
                    <div className="container">
                        {
                            searchResults.map(({ sys: { id, createdAt}, fields: { title, image, shortDescription, description, tags, skillLevel, duration, slug } }) => (
                                <div key={id} className="column-center">
                                    <article key={id} className="blogmaintile">
                                        
                                        <div className="blogtitle">
                                            <span key={title}>{title}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <section>
                                            <p className="blogdescription" key={shortDescription}>{shortDescription}</p>
                                            <span className="blogcreateddate" key={createdAt}>{Moment(createdAt).format('MMM DD YYYY')}</span>
                                            <span style={{display:"none"}} key={tags}>{tags}</span>
                                        </section>
                                        <section>
                                            <p className="bloglongdescription" key={description}>{description}</p>
                                        </section>
                                        <section className="col1">
                                            {
                                                <span className="difftags" key={skillLevel} >{skillLevel}</span>
                                            }
                                        </section>
                                        <span className="blogduration" key={duration} >{duration} min</span>
                                        <section className="col2">
                                            <a href={slug}>...more {'>'}{'>'}</a>
                                        </section>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  
      
    };
  
    return (
      <div className="posts__container">
        <div className="posts">{renderPosts()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require('axios');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require("cors");
const { get } = require('http');


const app = express()
const port = 5000
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/service/blogpost', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const blogposts = await axios({
     url: 'https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/some_space_id/entries?access_token=some_token&limit=1000&skip=0',
     method:"GET"
    });
     res.status(200).send(blogposts.data);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ fail: e.message });
  }
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./cssmodules/home.css";
import "./cssmodules/tutorialslist.css"
import "./cssmodules/singlepost.css";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Tutorials from "./components/Tutorials";
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import TutorialsList from './components/TutorialsList';
import SinglePost from './components/SinglePost';


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation/>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/tutorials" component={Tutorials} />
              <Route path="/tutorialslist" component={TutorialsList} />
              <Route path="/:id" component={SinglePost} />
          </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};


export default App;
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

serviceWorker.unregister();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is there:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const results = searchResults.filter(blog =>
    blog.fields.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) || blog.fields.title.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm) || blog.fields.shortDescription.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
      || blog.fields.shortDescription.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm)
    );
    setSearchResults(results);
}, [searchTerm, searchResults]);
```

Method `filter` returns a new array, you save it with `setSearchResults()`, React calls rerender, this `useEffect` detect a new searchResults, run its callback... and again and again.

Maybe you need in `useMemo` to calculate filtered results or calculate it in imminently after receiving from the server?

**Up**

Maybe something like this:

```js
  // Initiate a state for fetched posts.
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  // Fetch data from server on mount.
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data: { items } } = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/service/blogpost');

        setPosts(items);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // Extract Tags from Posts with memoization.
  const tags = useMemo(() => {
    return posts.reduce((result, post) => {
      const { fields: { tags } } = post;
      const normalizedTags = Array.isArray(tags) ? tags : [tags];

      return [
        ...result,
        ...normalizedTags,
      ];
    }, []);
  }, [posts]);

  // Filter Posts with memoization.
  const filteredPosts = useMemo(() => {
    const term = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

    return posts.filter((post) => {
      const title = post.fields.title.toLowerCase();
      const description = post.shortDescription.title.toLowerCase();

      return [title, description].includes(term); // You can extend the condition with a check of selected tags here.
    });
  }, [posts, searchTerm]);

  // Render `tags` and `filteredPosts` in your template.
```

Sorry if I don't understand your task

Comment: I have used useMemo() in the following way, but now my search is not working ``const results = React.useMemo(
            () =>
            searchResults.filter((blog) => {
                blog.fields.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) || blog.fields.title.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm) || blog.fields.shortDescription.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
                || blog.fields.shortDescription.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm)
              }),
            [searchTerm, searchResults]
          );``

Comment: Which was original working before integrating with server.js

Comment: Do you need to filter posts by input text and selected tags at the same time?

Comment: I will try today evening and will reply

Comment: All good now, I have upvoted and accepted your answer. I haven't seen your code comments properly.